# What are MigraDoc font sizes in pixels?

Tags: font-size, migradoc

What are MigraDoc font sizes (`Font.Size` property) in pixels? I would like to find an equivalent to css `small`, `medium`, `large`, `x-large`, `xx-large` and `xxx-large`.

EDIT

My question actually was what is the relation between MigraDoc unit of measure for font size (from the selected answer I found out it is point) and pixel. As an addition I said what I need it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MigraDoc does not know "pixels". All font sizes are in points.

Neither PDF nor RTF have "pixels".

There are 72 points per inch.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)

Comment: I was not trying to put pixels in MigraDoc, but to find their equivalents in MigraDoc measures. Knowing that those measures are points pointed me to a right direction.